# How to use Multiple end points in Graphql?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

I have scenario where I want to use two different Graphql Clients. Like

`const client2 = new ApolloClient({
 uri: "url1"
});`

`const client1 = new ApolloClient({
 uri: "url2"
});`

There is case where I want to use execute query on button client. There is form which going to submit to on `client1` working wrapped inside

`<Mutation>{....form} </Mutation>`

Now I have button inside form and onclicking button need to bring data from `client2`.

for this I tried like onClick event of button I excuted query like.

```
client2.query({
   query: ...querystring,
})
.then(result=>console.log('result',result))
```

But getting error like

> this.client.watchQuery is not function

```
react-apollo: 2.5.5
```

Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Could just be a typo in the post, but it looks like you're defining ```client1``` twice from what you've posted.  Otherwise, you should definitely be able to query using multiple clients,  Could you post more of the code where these operations are being performed?

Comment: Resolved. Actually There was `<Query>` in other place which has props wrong client name.